# error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred on login to the site example

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2015

i'm a newbie to programming & i'm trying to transfer an MVC project from one pc with SQL Server 2014 to another pc with SQL Server 2012 --- all is well except the fact that the 2012 pc is not able to load the databases that I am using for this project ...
one is called defaultConnection (Was scaffolded by visual studio mvc template on the first login)
and the other is called CarRentalDBEntities (was created in SQL Server and added to the project)...

both of witch I am able to update but not use ......

the error that i am getting is :

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred.
>   Unexpected error occurred inside a LocalDB instance API method call.
>   See the Windows Application event log for error details.)

windows log sais :

> Windows API call GetSvcBinPathByInstName returned error code: 2.
>   Windows system error message is: The system cannot find the file
>   specified. Reported at line: 3546.

when I try to refresh the databases in the server explorer i'm getting another error :

[MVC Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kvec.jpg)

I would be more than happy to hear some advice because iv'e tried fixing this for days with no luck at all .....

Comment: Is your database file in the App_Data folder of your project?

Comment: yes in the windows folder ...but when i try to add it as an existing file to the solution explorer it is marked as ignored......

Comment: Did you get an answer to this? I am in the same position and have haven't had any luck